# Converting GTM event to gtag event Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

My company was using GTM to track events, but we have switched to using gtag.js recently. Most of the conversion has gone well but I have one particular event I can't seem to convert correctly. It is for a service called Namogoo. We just track when their system fires an event so we can have a report in the GA portal.

The original GTM code is:

```
const someValue = 1

dataLayer.push({
    event: 'gtm.trackEvent',
    nB: someValue,
    trackEvent: {
        'category':'Namogoo',
        'action':'block',
        'label':'block',
        'value':someValue
    }
});
```

I have attempted a variety of things but my latest iteration which SHOWS the event in the realtime events interface but does not show on the custom report is:

```
gtag("event", "Namogoo", {
    "event_category":"Namogoo",
    "event_action":"block", 
    "event_label":"block",
    "event_value": someValue,
    "value":someValue
});
```

I'm basically just throwing spaghetti at the wall with the 'value' field. Any help would be appreciated. The custom report just operates on a Drilldown dimension created on the Namogoo event.

Comment: you can't exactly tell from the dataLayer push contents how the gtm container was configured.. maybe the tag that handles this also set custom dimensions, etc that are relevant to your analytics..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you XTOTHEL for your help.

The root of the issue turned out to be a missing custom_map in my gtag configuration to cover the custom dimension.

```js
gtag("event", "Namogoo", {
"event_category":"Namogoo",
"event_action":"block", 
"event_label":"block",
"nB":nB
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So your datalayer push implementation, this is how I understand it:

```
const someValue = 1
dataLayer.push({
    event: 'gtm.trackEvent',
    nB: someValue, //this is the same value as trackEvent.value
    trackEvent: {
        'category':'Namogoo', //maps to event category
        'action':'block', //maps event action
        'label':'block', //maps event label
        'value':someValue //same value as 'nB'
    }
});
```

For event tracking in gtag.js, this is the format:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

So putting everything together this should be what you're after:

```
const someValue = 1
gtag('event', 'block', {
  'event_category': 'Namogoo',
  'event_label': 'block',
  'value': someValue
});
```

Note, you have the label the same as the action, not too sure what purpose it serves.

Comment: I applied your suggestion on Friday, but tracking over the weekend I don't see it reporting more than before. We have our legacy site still running to serve older IE versions so we still see some hits from that site in GA, but I don't see the increase I would expect to match the reporting on Namogoo. I do appreciate the response.

Comment: Are you able to post links or screenshots so I can see what you are comparing in Namogoo?

Comment: I think I found the solution, deploying it now. The custom dimension we are reporting on was not in my config statement. Today I learned that. Once I confirm it I will post the solution. Thanks so much.

Comment: That's good to hear. Curious to why you guys are going from GTM to gtag.js? IMO gtag.js is less flexible in terms of tracking/digital marketing.

Comment: Not sure myself, was not with the company when these decisions were made.

Comment: Meant to update this. Issue was a missing 'custom_map' in my gtag configuration. Adding an answer directly. Your answer definitely helped get me most of the way there.